# Read a password protected .csv file

Tags: php, file, csv, passwords, unzip

I am trying to read/open an .csv file that is password protected with PHP. I obviously do have the password, and it does have content when I open it manually. I have tried this code, it does extract the file, but the file remains empty. I think the password is on the .csv file, and not on the .zip file, but I'm not too sure.

```
echo shell_exec("unzip 123.zip -P 123");
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("123.zip");
$zip->extractTo("extracted_files/");
```

Thanks

Comment: The CSV data format has no password feature

Comment: You are unzipping a ZIP archive with a password. I assume the result is a bunch of files created somewhere. I do not see any need to then try to access that ZIP file again with ZipArchive.

Comment: The shell_exec() doesn't really do anything, it just returns the zipfile name. It doesnt store anything anywhere. Tried something like this:  `echo shell_exec("unzip 123.zip -P 123 -x extracted_files/");` to extract it, but that doesnt help me either (probably doing it wrong)